# Javascript workaround for firefox iframe getComputedStyle bug

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe

I'm trying to use the following workaround for the hidden iframe/getComputedSytle firefox bug [548397](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=548397).

```
if (/firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
   window.oldGetComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle;
   window.getComputedStyle = function (element, pseudoElt) {
      var t = window.oldGetComputedStyle(element, pseudoElt);
      if (t === null) {
         return {};
      } else{
         return t;
      }
   };
}
```

However in my case I also need `getComputedSytle.getPropertyValue`  i.e. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: my_window.getComputedStyle(...).getPropertyValue is not a function
```

How can I add `getPropertyValue` to the above workaround?

Comment: Can’t you just rather use another method of “hiding” the iframe, other than `display:none`? In the bug report it is already suggested to use `visibility: hidden; position: absolute;` instead – the visual effect should be similar, but you wouldn’t have to deal with this “bug”. (“Bug” in quotes, because it is in the nature of elements with `display:none` that they are not actually rendered, so in reality there _are_ no computed style values to be read [although other browsers might handle this differently.])

Comment: I hit this problem today (in FireFox 47) even though my iframe itself was not set to `display:none`. The symptom was that `iframeResizer` was failing only in FireFox. The reason was that we hit this bug because the iframe was contained by a child of a collapsed accordion segment so was not displayed on page load. So thanks both for the proposed workaround and solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just create an empty function:

```
if (/firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
   window.oldGetComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle;
   window.getComputedStyle = function (element, pseudoElt) {
      var t = window.oldGetComputedStyle(element, pseudoElt);
      if (t === null) {
         return {
            getPropertyValue: function(){}
         };
      } else{
         return t;
      }
   };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution would be this one

```
function setFirefoxPolyfill() {
  if (/firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    window.oldGetComputedStyle = window .getComputedStyle;
    window.getComputedStyle = function (element, pseudoElt) {
      var t = window.oldGetComputedStyle(element, pseudoElt);
      if (t === null) {
        return element.style;
      } else{
        return t;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

in case of `null` response you just return element styles with all prototyped methods and fields